# Is it possible to change Git standard messages when committing?

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit

Is it possible to change the part:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
```

To say:

```
# Staged:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using a `prepare-commit-msg` hook. This is a script in `.git/hooks/` which is run between Git's generation of the commit message, and the commit message being opened in your editor.

As a simple example, copy the below text into a new file called `prepare-commit-msg` in `.git/hooks/`.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i '0,/# Changes to be committed:/c# Staged:' "$1"
```

If you find it doesn't work immediately, check it's executable: run `chmod +x .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`.

(The script is a `sed` one-liner to replace every line up to and including the "Changes to be committed" line with the text "# Staged:")

Answer (score 0):

In an easy way, just that part, no.

But you could use the commit-msg hook to modify the commit msg.