# How to suppress "Changes not staged for commit"?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

How do I suppress the "Changes not staged for commit" output when committing? Note that:

- I know I can do `> /dev/null`, but I'm hoping not to suppress other things.
- I'm not talking about the *commit message* -- I'm talking about what its printed to the terminal.

Comment: You are asking about the default commit message that is displayed?

Comment: Why bother? It's just an information about files changed but not included into the commit. It's useful when you prepare a series of commits from a given changed worktree.

Comment: @user3159253: Just because you might find it useful doesn't mean I do...

Comment: take a look at REPO/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample, they have an example which shows how to comment out the 'conflicts' section that could be adapted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the default comments in the git commit message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message)

Comment: @ddr2: Not a duplicate, see my edit.

Comment: this is confusing. What's that output ? Can you give us an example ? Except from the one commented-out in the default commit message (if you enter a commit message via an editor) ... the only other one I can think of is in `git status` which is a completely different matter ?

Comment: If you're not using an editor, you will get something like `[master 436246b] test 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)` as output from commiting, so nothing containing "changes not staged for commit" ;)

Comment: @ddr2: Sorry it's confusing, I encounter it when I try to commit with no files added. (It's part of a script, obviously not something I would do by hand.)

Comment: so I've been checking a bit the git.git code, a funny solution could be to use --allow-empty, allowing the creation of empty commits so you never see that message ;)

Comment: @ddr2: Yeah but I don't want that haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging in the [git.git](https://github.com/git/git) codebase, I am afraid you should be designing a way to ignore those lines in your script.

During a commit, if you don't use `--allow-empty`, git will go through [that code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/37023ba381b6d251d7140a997b39b566dbc63c42/builtin/commit.c#L908):

```
if (!commitable && whence != FROM_MERGE && !allow_empty &&
    !(amend && is_a_merge(current_head))) {
    s->display_comment_prefix = old_display_comment_prefix;
    run_status(stdout, index_file, prefix, 0, s);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

And `run_status` does the following thing:

```
switch (status_format) {
    case STATUS_FORMAT_SHORT:
        wt_shortstatus_print(s);
        break;
    case STATUS_FORMAT_PORCELAIN:
        wt_porcelain_print(s);
        break;
    case STATUS_FORMAT_UNSPECIFIED:
        die("BUG: finalize_deferred_config() should have been called");
        break;
    case STATUS_FORMAT_NONE:
    case STATUS_FORMAT_LONG:
        wt_status_print(s);
        break;
    }
}
```

`STATUS_FORMAT_PORCELAIN` (use `--porcelain`) and `STATUS_FORMAT_SHORT` (`git config status.short true`) will result in the same minified output:

```
 M bla.txt
```

and `STATUS_FORMAT_LONG` (AND `STATUS_FORMAT_NONE`, not sure why ?), will result in the usual output:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   bla.txt
```

That said, let's not despair, this is software we're talking about, there is always a way around the problem (I still need to completely test this though ;) )

You could use `--allow-empty` to get pass that code branch and create an empty commit. Then, you chain that with a `post-commit` hook that checks whether the latest commit is empty, if it is, the hook runs `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and you could be good to go ?