# TortoiseGit Git Commit message from script

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, tortoisegit, pre-commit-hook

I have generated Start Commit Hook in TortoiseGit which calls *StartComit.bat* file and option *"Wait for the script to finish"* is enabled.

The content of the bat file is

```
echo "Some more info...." >> %1
```

The script is getting called **before** Commit dialog opens but it's not working, I'm not getting any text in Message field.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Just to make question more clear I'm trying to fallow this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967136/596935 and do a similar thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%1 is the path to a file containing all selected files when starting the commit dialog and not the path to the file for the message which is %2.

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks for a manual regarding the parameters.

Thus,

```
echo Some more info.... >> %2
```

should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for help, I started looking at different direction here with prepare-commit-msg hook which didn't worked either