# TortoiseGit - change default merge message

Tags: git, tortoisegit

#### System description:

- Windows 7
- git version 2.10.1.windows.1
- TortoiseGit 2.3.0.0

---

#### I want:

The merge commit message to be different in a **fully** automated manner (*no* manual `amend`)

---

#### Summary:

On windows, using tortoiseGit, there is no `prepare-commit-msg` [hook](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks), only `start-commit-hook` and **no matter** what the hook script is, I get a windows popup error:

```
%1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Also, I would prefer to **only** change the commit messages which are "merges".

---

#### Steps:

setup the hook:

[image]

Set the working tree path to be same as my project's path,
and in "Command Line To Execute" I select the file I prepared:

```
.git\hooks\prepare-commit-msg
```

which its content is `echo "test"`.

Then I try to do a commit and get this error:

[image]

I've made sure that this script file is indeed the file which is used, 
because if I delete it, I get this message:

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows, SourceTree and Git are you using? Is SourceTree using the embedded Git or the system Git (ie your own Git installed separately from SoruceTree)

Comment: @VonC - sorry, was about to add those then forgot and just posted. now it's there.

Comment: Related to - http://stackoverflow.com/q/38371758/104380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TortoiseGit hooks are fully independent of vanilla Git hooks.

You can use any script language or executable as TortoiseGit hook script. However, in the configuration you have to enter a a valid Windows executable as command, e.g. an `.exe` file, for `.js` or `.vbs` scripts you need to specify the interpreter (`wscript` or `cscript`) and the path to the script as the interpreter parameter (cf. [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-dia-hook-edit)). For executing a bash script I think you need to execute bash.exe with the appropriate parameters to a script - I haven't tested this before.

The executed hook gets some parameters from TortoiseGit, those are documented [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks), e.g. the `Start-commit` is called when the commit dialog is opened and gets three cli parameters: PATH MESSAGEFILE CWD, whereas PATH is a path to a file containing all entries of the commit dialog, MESSAGEFILE is the path to a file where you can put the contents to which should be used as commit message and CWD is the working tree path.

Examples can be found on https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/tree/master/contrib/hook-scripts/client-side

PS: In order to check whether this is a merge commit you can check for the existance of `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.

Comment: How do I check `.git/MERGE_HEAD` ?

Comment: Sorry, was AFK: The hook script gets the path to the working tree as a parameter. Just append `.git/MERGE_HEAD` to it and check whether this file exists. If yes: it's a merge commit, otherwise not.

Comment: how do I check? I don't know any of these things.. sorry, It's outside the scope of my work as a client-side developer.. I've never had to do these things or knew of their existence, and google has nearly zero answers on this topic of "tortoisegit hook examples"

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @MrTux what should I do if TortoiseGit does not find the interpreter's environment variable? Under the System Variables I have put the PWSH variable that points to pwsh.exe. Then, in the Command Line To Execute in TortoiseGit, I wrote PWSH %root%\'myscript.ps1. After that, I got the message "The system cannot find the file specified". However, if I write the full path to pwsh.exe in the text box, myscript.ps1 is executed.

Comment: @MrTux I got it myself. I cannot use any environment variable in this text box, I can only use all the things that are in my PATH environment variable. After I added the path to pwsh.exe to the PATH, my TortoiseGit .ps1 hook worked as expected.