# Set default message in GIT commit field

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

I've set in `C:\Users\myUser\.gitconfig`

```
[commit]
    template = ~/message.txt     //btw: i've also tried: ~user/message.txt
```

and saved some text in `message.txt` in that same folder.

however, when I try to commit one of my repos, commit field is still empty:
[image]

do i miss any step?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i've read that and that's why i posted this question.

Comment: I cannot replicate. Consider trying with the command line and seeing if the message is populated there?

Comment: Try using the full path: `template = C:/users/username/message.txt`

Comment: Do `cd ~`, then do `pwd` ... what path do you see?

Comment: probably my mistake is that i havent mentioned that i use `TortoiseGit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to specify the full path in your config. For example this is my config on linux and this works:

```
[commit]
template = /home/mmauksch/.gitmessage
```

Which in your case should probably be:

```
[commit]
template = C:/Users/myUser/.gitmessage
```

because there's a good chance that the concept of `~` as "home directory of the current user" doesn't really make sense in a windows context.