# Visual Studio default changes message

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-commit

It there any way for Visual Studio 2017 Team Explorer to show a default message in the **Changes** text-box?

I already tried the both methods, `prepare-commit-msg` and `commit.template`, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which method did you try? There are multiple answers to that question.

Comment: @TTT, i tried both methods (aslo updated my question).