# Config item to set default commit message header line prefix

Tags: git

Frequently policies in project are to connect commits with task or bug ID. For this prefixing every commit message header line with such ID is made. Any Git config setting exists to set default commit message header line prefix? Setting can be scoped to branch or repository.

Comment: You could edit the default commit message? Or use a tool like comitizen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start a git commit message with a hashmark (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788092/start-a-git-commit-message-with-a-hashmark)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the default comments in the git commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message)